# Convert an XML object back into a string in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, xml-parsing

In ColdFusion, I can parse a string of XML formatted data into an XML Object
using `xmlParse()`. How can I convert it back into a string?

When I tried using `toString()` it throws an error that "it can't convert complex object to simple objects....", which is ironic because that's what it's supposed to do.

I need to use `XMLTransform()` which *requires* the first argument to be an xml string. But I also need to use `xmlSearch()` to get a node to pass into my transform, and xmlSearch returns an xmlObject. So now I need to put that object back into xml string format to pass into xmlTransform.

Comment: Actually the documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e8e.html) states that the first argument can be "an XML document in string format, or an XML document object".  Are you getting an error?

Comment: *Are you getting an error?*  - If so, please post your code and the full error message.

Comment: You need to provide some code demonstrating `toString()` not working for you, because it absolutely *does* work with XML.

Comment: And `xmlTransform()` will take an XML object (ie: not just a string) quite happily.  So there's def more to this that you're letting on...?

Answer (score 3):

Thank You - all;

The cause of my problem is that due to the structure of this particular XML, my XMLSearch returned an array with multiple items. So trying to use `toString()` on that result caused an error.

**Code:**

```
    pXML = xmlParse( _xml );
    myElements = XmlSearch( pXML, "//data" );   
    writeoutput( toString( myElements ) );
```

**Result/Error:**

```
    Error Occurred While Processing Request
    Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

**Solution**

```
    writeOutput( toString( myElements[1] ) );
```

The XML has multiple nested nodes named "data", and `XMLSearch()` was traversing and returning each node.

Thanks again for you input.

Comment: OK, so just to be clear, you weren't trying to `toString(someXml)`, you were trying to `toString(anArray)` (because `xmlSearch()` returns an array, not XML).  Tip for next time: include the code that's giving you a problem, rather than just describe it.  We coulda solved that for you in about 5sec... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try just outputing the XML text inside cfxml and then changing back into string format like so:

```
<cfxml variable="xmlObject" casesensitive="yes">
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
</rss>
</cfxml>
<cfoutput>#ToString(xmlObject)#</cfoutput>
```

OR

```
<cffile action="write" file="#ExpandPath('RSS.xml')#" output="#ToString(xmlObject)#">
```

For details on `toString()` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f9e.html

If that's not what you need, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the XML in a cfsavecontent. And use the variable as a string